# how to set alignment of label in HeaderTemplate in individual column in gridview in asp .net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

how to set alignment of label in HeaderTemplate in individual column in gridview in asp .net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
```

for example in the template field tag

and for bound field something like

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="XYZ" DataField="xyz" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
```

Comment: <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle> only set for whole set of header, not individual one, and this case is header template include a label which need to be set alignment

Comment: @mathew: HeaderStyle is also available as child of ItemTemplate, it should be applicable to only per column.